# Java-ML(LibSVM) How can I get the classes probabilities?

Tags: java, machine-learning, libsvm

We are using Java-ML(LibSVM) in order to execute the SVM algorithm over a multi-class problem

```
        Classifier clas = new LibSVM();
        clas.buildClassifier(data);
        Dataset dataForClassification= FileHandler.loadDataset(new File(.), 0, ",");
        /* Counters for correct and wrong predictions. */
        int correct = 0, wrong = 0;
        /* Classify all instances and check with the correct class values */
        for (Instance inst : dataForClassification) {
            Object predictedClassValue = clas.classify(inst);
            Map<Object,Double> map = clas.classDistribution(inst);
            Object realClassValue = inst.classValue();
            if (predictedClassValue.equals(realClassValue))
                correct++;
            else
                wrong++;
        }
```

the `classDistributtion()` returns a standard vector ( meaning all values are 0 but one value which equals to 1)

java-ml - http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the other answers, it is possible to output probability estimates for SVMs and LibSVM does do this. However, I'm fairly sure you can't use this feature from Java-ML. The file `LibSVM.java` only ever refers to the function `svm_predict_values` and never `svm_predict_probabilities`. It probably wouldn't be too hard to add this functionality in to Java-ML if you felt you really needed it.

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK, LibSVM is a deterministic classifier, meaning that the only distributions you will see are concentrated on a single class i.e. a standard vector. This is different than a probabilistic classifier such as Naive Bayes, which may give values different than 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: the libSVM can do multi-class and can estimate the distribution, I am just not sure how to do it using Java-ml...